# Add class to child element but not to parent

Tags: jquery, select

I want to add a class to one element at a time. The element may be a child of a parent element that the click event is also applied to. whats the best method to add the class to the child element only, but not the parent. Heres an example, click on the child div and see that the class is also added to all parent elements. I can think of a few ways to do this but I want to make sure Im using the best solution. Basically I want the class to only be added to the element clicked regardless of its parents with the same class.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aiGJb

```
<div id="parent" class="element">
  <div id="child" class="element">
   <div id="childdd" class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try stop "bubbling" using "return false;" at the end of click handler after addClass().

Comment: It works, Dont know how this works. How does return false; prevent the other event handlers on the parent elements from being triggered but not the one clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in "bubbling".

Here is the great explanation of how this "bubble" magic works.
The "Bubbling and capturing" article: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Your solution is to stop "bubbling" using `return false;` at the end of your click handler:

```
$(".element").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    return false;
});
```